# Choose the page to import from Google sheet to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

I'm trying to link a Gsheet page to an excel using a Macro.
The link is working but when I copy the Url of the page I want to import into Excel it automatically import the first page of the Gsheet.
Is it possible to choose the page I want to import?

Here is the code I have done to import the page by copying the URL:

```
Sub I_G()

Sheets("Feuil1").Select
resultats = InputBox("Copy the URL of the data collection", "URL")
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"URL;" & resultats _
, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
.BackgroundQuery = True
.Refresh

End With
End Sub
```